# Jenkins withEnv in pipeline doesn't set environment variables on Windows

Tags: windows, jenkins, environment-variables

I want to be able to change environment variables on Windows in a Jenkins pipeline, and only in that pipeline, how do I do it?

The environment variables are set in the system as:

```
XXX_DEV_DATA_DIR = E:\tools\jenkins\workspace\data\XXX-IDM
XXX_DEV_LIBS_DIR = E:\tools\jenkins\workspace\dev\libs
```

I tried the withEnv command but it has no effect:

```
node
{
    withEnv(["XXX_DEV_LIBS_DIR=E:\\tools\\jenkins\\workspace\\dev\\libs', 'XXX_DEV_DATA_DIR=E:\\tools\\jenkins\\workspace\\data\\XXX-IDM-Testing"])
    {
        dir('E:\\tools\\jenkins\\workspace\\samples\\GetXXXSettings\\bin\\x64\\Release')
        {
            bat 'GetXXXSettings.exe'
        }
    }
}
```

The GetXXXSettings.exe application:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("XXX_DEV_DATA_DIR");
        var libs = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("XXX_DEV_LIBS_DIR");

        Console.WriteLine("XXX ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"XXX_DEV_DATA_DIR = {data}");
        Console.WriteLine($"XXX_DEV_LIBS_DIR = {libs}");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("END");
    }
}
```

The result is as follows:

```
XXX ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES

XXX_DEV_DATA_DIR = E:\tools\jenkins\workspace\data\XXX-IDM
XXX_DEV_LIBS_DIR = E:\tools\jenkins\workspace\dev\libs', 'XXX_DEV_DATA_DIR=E:\tools\jenkins\workspace\data\XXX-IDM-Testing

END
```

The environment variable XXX_DEV_DATA_DIR is unchanged, I'm not sure what is happening to XXX_DEV_LIBS_DIR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you issue with quotes at withEnv, try updating it

```
node
{
    withEnv(['XXX_DEV_LIBS_DIR=E:\\tools\\jenkins\\workspace\\dev\\libs', 'XXX_DEV_DATA_DIR=E:\\tools\\jenkins\\workspace\\data\\XXX-IDM-Testing'])
    {
        dir('E:\\tools\\jenkins\\workspace\\samples\\GetXXXSettings\\bin\\x64\\Release')
        {
            bat 'GetXXXSettings.exe'
        }
    }
}
```